# how to remove element from JSON array in golang?

Tags: go

I have a array of JSON string

ex:

```
[
 {
  "name":"abc"
  "age":25
 }
 {
  "name":"xyz"
  "age":"26"
 }
]
```

In run time I want to remove "name" from array . How can we do it . I don't want to unmarshal it .

```
[
     {
      "age":25
     }
     {
      "age":"26"
     }
  ]
```

Comment: If you do not want to unmarshal it, the only way is to parse the bytes yourself, you will end up implementing a state machine.

Comment: You might be able to do it with regex if you really must not unmarshel it.

Comment: What's wrong with unmarshaling/modifying/marshaling? That seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do what you want by using, this packages [gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson),  and [sjson](https://github.com/tidwall/sjson).

example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
    "github.com/tidwall/sjson"
)

func main() {
    bJSON := []byte(`       
            [
                {
                    "name": "abc",
                    "age": 25
                },
                {
                    "name": "xyz",
                    "age": 26
                }
            ]
    `)

    newJSON := bJSON
    var err error

    result := gjson.GetBytes(bJSON, "#.age")

    for i := range result.Array() {
        newJSON, err = sjson.DeleteBytes(newJSON, strconv.Itoa(i)+".age")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(string(newJSON))
}
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "name": "xyz"
  }
]
```

Comment: can we do it without adding "key"

Answer (score 1):

If you literally don't want to unmarshal it, you'll be stuck doing some sort of regex replacement, or building a state machine (effectively unmarshaling it yourself). If you're asking the question, then you shouldn't take this approach. This approach is for very advanced users only, and has no advantages except in very extremely rare situations.

I assume you just don't want to bother with the effort of writing code to unmarshal it, though, and wouldn't mind a tool that does the work for you, even if that involves unmarshaling under the covers.

If I'm right in my guess, you could consider a library like [gabs](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs) (disclaimer: I've never used this library), which provides for easy JSON manipulation.  But of course it unmarshals the JSON in the process, then remarshals it when you ask for the result.